# How to test android application using android studio?

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, automation, android-testing

i am an QA i am performing Manual Testing for testing the Android Applications.

Now, i am planning to test android applications by using automation tools.
i tried Robotium. it seemed to an paid version. so i dropped Robotium.

i am preferring Android studio. i am not having sufficient knowledge over android studio.

While gathering data about this, i found Android Studio has Monkey and Monkey Runner. for Unit Testing.

Is there any other tool can be useful for Android Testing? 
and say how to test applications with that tools.

Comment: Monkey Runner has nothing to do with JUnit tests. It just mashes on the keyboard as a monkey would...

Comment: can you suggest any other tools to test android applications?

Comment: @shark:I think what you are talking about is `monkey` tool. `MonkeyRunner` has much more intelligence than `monkey`

Comment: @Rilwan care to elaborate?

Comment: Monkey tool: just mashes keyboard as real monkey would do.
Monkeyrunner tool: we can controller the touches,typing,etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google your question will give you answers.
All the below you can do with studio. From android developer website-

[AndroidJUnitRunner](http://AndroidJUnitRunner:): JUnit 4-compatible test runner for Android

[Espresso: UI testing framework](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#Espresso) -suitable for functional UI testing within an app

[UI Automator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator)-UI testing framework; suitable for cross-app functional UI testing across system and installed apps

Start from uiautomator basics!